# How to put a lock on a database table resource

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building a financial web app, sort of an e-banking application. Whenever a transaction is being performed e.g Funds transfer, a transaction charge is deducted and updates the system account's earnings/balance by querying the current balance and adding up the deducted charge and then finally updating the balance field.

Now my problem is that when multiple transactions maybe 200 of them are simultaneously executing by different users with different accounts, there is a discrepancy between the total earnings balance that I expected from what is being actually registered in the system. I believe it has something to do with having to asynchronous nature of server-request or something, how can I prevent this??

Comment: I believe [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yah am sure this will do it. trying now

Answer (score 0):

There is transaction in `codeigniter`. you can refer [Codeigniter Transaction](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html)

you can use as

```
$this->db->trans_start();
```

YOUR QUERY / QUERYS

```
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Comment: I am actually using codeigniter transactions, but yet this is happening. And I thought the point of using transactions was to make sure that processes relating to database manipulation executes in their entirety or rollback if one step fails. To better clarify my question, if I was to use java, I would of course perform each transaction in multiple threads but would synchronize  that one function that updates the master account's balance.

Comment: yes, because CI run all query  in `trans_strict` (Strict mode), you can make it false also if u want.